# What is wrong with this code because the submit button is not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here is the code. It is wordpress pages that I created.Both pages are in same folder. I am sending data from  leadgen.php to page-success.php

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/success-page",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'name=' +name+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&content='+'&city='city+'&date='+date+'&event_type='+event_type+'&service='+service+'&guests='+guests+'&budget='+budget+'&locality='+locality+'&food_type='+food_type+'&venue_type='+venue_type+'&photography_type='+photography_type;

    success:function(data){
    document.location.href = 'http://localhost/success-page/';
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
});
```

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: 1) Check the console for errors 2) Provide an object to `data` instead of hacking together a querystring by yourself 3) What's the point of making an AJAX request when you're going to redirect the page immediately afterwards anyway?

Comment: Take a step back and rethink what you're doing. Your current code makes no sense.

Comment: actually the plan was just to stay on that page so i did it. Now I need it on another page. So should I continue with this one or send data using normal php form post technique.

Answer (score 0):

Post you data like this, do not use query string.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost/success-page",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
      Name: name,
      Email: email
      // more data you want to post....
    },
   success:function(data){
       document.location.href = 'http://localhost/success-page/';
    },
  error:function (){}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you are not concatenating query string in the correct format.

Please try below code.

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/success-page",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'name=' +name+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&content='+content+'&city='+city+'&date='+date+'&event_type='+event_type+'&service='+service+'&guests='+guests+'&budget='+budget+'&locality='+locality+'&food_type='+food_type+'&venue_type='+venue_type+'&photography_type='+photography_type;

    success:function(data){
    document.location.href = 'http://localhost/success-page/';
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
});

I hope this will helps you
```